# I am trying to create a custom view that shows only certain metrics (Page Views, Unique Page Views) Is this possible?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a custom view that shows only certain metrics, like Page Views, Unique Page Views but excludes other metrics like Bounces. I have looked in the custom reports and under Admin with no success. Is this possible, and if so how do I achieve this custom view?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what problems you are facing? In Custom reports, are you remembering to select associated dimensions as well? I don't see why you wouldn't be able to pull a flat report with pages (dimension), and pageviews and unique pageviews as metrics.

If you are looking just for a custom view, then I don't believe that would be possible. Perhaps a close approximation would be a custom dashboard:

[image]